# Recording questions from a conference crowd

Tags: microphone-technique, microphone-positioning, conference

As a small user-group we regularly organize mini conference with a few talks and 60-140 attendees.

We have a nice *portable* setup for recording the talks (Camera->HDMI->MacBook->Wirecast). The presenter sounds great thanks to the *RodeLink FilmMaker*.

**The next challenge is to find how to record the questions from the attendees**. (small team, pretty relaxed atmosphere: we don't want to bring a mic to the person)

Here are the combinations I gathered:

1. condenser / cardiod, placed 1 m in front of the presenter, pointing to the crowd
2. condenser / cardiod, placed on each front side of the crowd, 2m high?(basically above the crowd)
3. XY (because we have a Zoom H4) in front of the room.
4. boundary mic? Not sure how to place it.

It seems to be an interesting challenge because we organize those events in different places with very different acoustics (company lounges, one with very high ceiling...)

**What do you think would work reasonably well, but also as light as possible?**

Additional requirement: we are live-mixing/recording, so the sound must be fed to MacBook, not just recorded.

Note: I know there is no magical solution, I'm only trying to find a simple way to make the questions intelligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is to just have the speaker repeat the question before answering it. If it were that simple you wouldn't see TV professionals passing around a mic in the audience. But if you don't really care to get good quality then just placing a few mics around is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I know there is no easy solution. What I'm trying to find is the best tradeoff.
I only need to make the questions intelligible.

Comment: @PiorBastida well then in that case option 2 is a good solution and keeping the mice above the heads of the audience.

Comment: Do you confirm that I should aim for a cardiod? Super/hyper cardiod would pick up more noise/echo and the presenter, right?
Or maybe it doesn't matter much at this point?

Comment: @PiorBastida if you are using a PA system also then yes you wouldn't want that in the background of the audience microphones because of echo etc. like you said.